# MATLAB: How to randomly increase a random element in a matrix by one 'popping'?

Tags: matlab, random, indexing, location

I am stuck on a question and don't know how to go about it:

Write a function that given a matrix M of numbers representing locations and the number of popcorn pieces that have previously popped at each, returns a matrix with one more popped piece randomly added. In addition, the function returns the row-column coordinate where the latest piece popped.

For example:

```
>> a = zeros(2)
a = 
  0  0
  0  0
>> aa = popcorn(a)
aa = 
  1  0
  0  0
>>[aaa rc] = popcorn(aa)
aaa
  2  0
  0  0
rc =
  1  1
>> [aaaa rc] = popcorn(aaa)
aaaa = 
  2  0
  0  1
rc = 
  2  2
>>aaaaa = popcorn(aaaa)
aaaaa = 
  2  1
  0  1
```

So far, what i have is:

```
function output  = popcorn(M)
[w, z] = size(M);
a = randi(w);
f = randi(z);
b = w(a,f);
output = b;
```

But then i get an error saying:

> Attempted to access w(1,2); index out of bounds because `numel(w)=1`.
>       Error in popcorn (line 5)
>       `b = w(a,f);`

And its here where I'm stuck, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to index into a single integer `w` - which is the number of rows. You need to index into the original matrix.

Where you have

```
b = w(a,f);
```

You should have

```
b = M(a,f);
```

to find the value that you need to increment. Your code is not complete, with this fix, you still have not incremented the value or returned the co-ordinates. However, as this is a practice problem, it is best if you attempt those parts yourself.

Comment: Hi Neil, 
I have taken your advice is this is now the code i have.
    function output  = popcorn(M)
[w, z] = size(M);
a = randi(w);
f = randi(z);
b = M(a,f)+1;
output = b;

Though now i only get a single value, and am now wondering on how to input this increment into the original matrix 
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hint: The term `M(a,f)` can be on the left hand side of an assignment.